# How to convert text list to float list - TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python

I have a list that is all text values. The actual list is 124 values long but looks something like this:

```py
p_list = ['', '0.005', '3.0', '20.0', '0.15', '200.0', '0.7', '0.03', '12.0', '13.0', '70.0', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

I want to convert it to a float with the following code:

```py
p_list = [float(i) if i != '' else None for i in p_list]
```

The above code gives the error:

```py
File "C:\Users\\...\reports\views.py", line 112, in <listcomp>
p_list = [float(i) if i != '' else None for i in p_list] 

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

How should I correct this?

Comment: what python version you are using?

Comment: It works for me, try assigning the new list to different variable

Comment: @ΕυάγγελοςΓρηγορόπουλος 
I am using python 3.9.

Comment: works for me too ,seems like you trying to float again somewhere that the value is already None

Comment: It did work for me in either Python 3.9+.  You could simplify it to - `[float(i) if i  else None for i in p_list]`

Comment: no issue with your list and  list comprehension ... bug must be something else in line 112

Answer (score 0):

```
p_list = ['', '0.005', '3.0', '20.0', '0.15', '200.0', '0.7', '0.03', 
'12.0', '13.0', '70.0', '', '', '', '', '', '']

p_list = [float(i) if i != '' else None for i in p_list]


print(p_list) # See below output , it worked for me
```

[image]